# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when upgrading WebSocket connection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a game server from TCP to WebSockets. It worked fine with TCP, but since implementing a switching protocol mechanism to support web sockets I now get an exception upon decoding the message.

Exception I receive:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: count ('-2103261134') must be a non-negative value. (Parameter 'count') Actual value was -2103261134.
 at System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowNegative[T](T value, String paramName)    at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)    at Game.Networking.Packets.NetworkPacketDecoder.DecodePacketsFromBytes(Byte[] packet)
 in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Packets/NetworkPacketDecoder.cs:line 24
    at Game.Networking.Client.NetworkClientProcessComponent.OnReceivedAsync(Int32 bytesReceived)
 in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Client/NetworkClientProcessComponent.cs:line 101
    at Game.Networking.Client.NetworkClientProcessComponent.StartListening() in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Client/NetworkClientProcessComponent.cs:line 43 
[15:37:24 ERR] System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: count ('-2103252104') must be a non-negative value. (Parameter 'count') Actual value was -2103252104.
    at System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowNegative[T](T value, String paramName)
    at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count) 
   at Game.Networking.Packets.NetworkPacketDecoder.DecodePacketsFromBytes(Byte[] packet)
 in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Packets/NetworkPacketDecoder.cs:line 24
    at Game.Networking.Client.NetworkClientProcessComponent.OnReceivedAsync(Int32 bytesReceived)
 in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Client/NetworkClientProcessComponent.cs:line 101
    at Game.Networking.Client.NetworkClientProcessComponent.StartListening()
 in /mnt/storage/dev/GameEmulator/Game.Networking/Client/NetworkClientProcessComponent.cs:line 43
```

Here is the only code I've added, inside `private async Task OnReceivedAsync(int bytesReceived)` which gets called upon receiving bytes.

```
var stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

if (stringData.Length >= 3 && Regex.IsMatch(stringData, "^GET"))
{
    await UpgradeConnectionAsync(stringData);
    return;
}
```

UpgradeConnectionAsync method:

```
private async Task UpgradeConnectionAsync(string data)
{
    const string eol = "\r\n"; // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker

    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + eol
        + "Connection: Upgrade" + eol
        + "Upgrade: websocket" + eol
        + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                )
            )
        ) + eol
        + eol);

    await _networkClient.WriteToStreamAsync(response);
}
```

Messages the client sent to the server (chrome dev tools, UTF8):

```
Binary Message  34 B    
15:37:24.522
�NITRO-1-6-6HTML5

Binary Message  18 B    
15:37:24.522
    sdfdfdf!

Binary Message  6 B 
15:37:44.522

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:38:04.802

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:38:24.802

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:38:44.802

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:39:04.802

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:40:05.802

$

Binary Message  6 B 
15:41:06.803

$
```

NetworkPacketDecoder

```
public class NetworkPacketDecoder
{
    private readonly NetworkingConstants _constants;

    protected NetworkPacketDecoder(NetworkingConstants constants)
    {
        _constants = constants;
    }

    protected List<NetworkPacket> DecodePacketsFromBytes(byte[] packet)
    {
        if (packet.Length < _constants.FrameLengthByteCount || packet.Length > _constants.BufferByteSize - _constants.FrameLengthByteCount)
        {
            return new List<NetworkPacket>();
        }

        using var reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packet));
        var packetLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(reader.ReadBytes(4));

        var packetData = reader.ReadBytes(packetLength);

        using var br2 = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packetData));
        var packetId = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(br2.ReadBytes(2));

        var content = new byte[packetData.Length - 2];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(packetData, 2, content, 0, packetData.Length - 2);

        var packets = new List<NetworkPacket>();
        
        if (reader.BaseStream.Length - 4 > packetLength)
        {
            var extra = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length - reader.BaseStream.Position];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(packet, (int)reader.BaseStream.Position, extra, 0, (int)(reader.BaseStream.Length - reader.BaseStream.Position));

            packets.AddRange(DecodePacketsFromBytes(extra));
        }
        
        packets.Add(new NetworkPacket(packetId, content));
        return packets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your assumption about the endianness is wrong? `ReadInt32LittleEndian()` produces the signed integer `852009602` for the same value

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen could you elaborate? How would this differ from a standard TCP connection to a WebSocket one which is being switched?

Comment: I'm simply saying that using `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian` you've made an assumption about the incoming byte order, and the results you're getting (a negative integer value) suggests that that assumption might be wrong

Comment: Why don't you use the proper `WebSocket` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-8.0 rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Charlieface A lot of code is already written with TCP in mind so I was looking for a slick solution which didn't mean rewriting other areas of the code base. Plus from research its as simple as sending an upgrade protocol message back to the client which I've done. The 4 bytes being read should decode the message length from length prefixing framing on the client side, the fact I'm upgrading the protocol shouldn't change this outcome in my opinion. It sounds more like the client isn't respecting the response and trying to send data the original way anyway, I'll have to reach out to find out.

Comment: Also to add to this, TCP support is still required, which means if I implemented a WebSocket solution it would probably add more complexity having two gateways as such.

Comment: You can create a WebSocket from an arbitrary stream so you cna just pass your existing `NetworkStream` to that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket.createfromstream?view=net-8.0 but I would caution against what you are doing. Bare TCP is fraught with many many pitfalls, there is a reason why you are recommended to use an existing protocol.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the only code I've added, inside `private async Task OnReceivedAsync(int bytesReceived)` which gets called upon receiving bytes.

Are you saying that you literally just added HTTP handshake handling to your custom TCP protocol? That can't possibly work. And indeed, this:

```
var packetLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(reader.ReadBytes(4));
```

**is not** how WebSocket packet length is encoded.

**WebSocket protocol is not just HTTP handshake followed by an arbitrary TCP stream.** WebSocket protocol defines its own framing. Frames look like this:

```
      0                   1                   2                   3
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
     |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
     |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
     |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
     | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
     |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
     | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
     +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In particular payload length is encoded in different ways (as 7 bits, 7+16 bits, or 7+64 bits), depending on its value. For example for payloads up to 125 bytes the length will not even take 1 byte (7 bits only). And you read 4 bytes, that's why you get the exception. And you don't even start in correct place. First 9 bits is: FIN and RSV flags, opcode and masking flag. You don't seem to process any of that. You don't react to opcodes, e.g. ping/pong frames have to be handled differently. You also don't seem to handle fragmentation and packet concatenation at TCP level. Which btw tells me that your original protocol is not correct as well.

On top of that you parse HTTP upgrade request via regex. Which is debatable as well. At least incompatible with newer versions of HTTP. And you didn't show us how you actually read the HTTP upgrade request. These are not length prefixed but terminated by concrete sequence of chars. And due to fragmentation and/or packet concatenation it is not so trivial. Somehow I doubt you've done it correctly, correct me if I'm wrong.

If you really want to implement WebSockets on your own, you need to read [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5). Plus you should do proper HTTP parsing, which is hard on its own. You have to learn a lot about low level networking.

**But my real advice is: don't do that.** It's a tedious and error prone job. Honestly those protocols (HTTP and WebSocket) are very complicated. Unnecessarily complicated. They don't have to be, this is in many cases due to historical reasons and the requirement of backwards compatibility. So use an existing implementation, and let others deal with those issues.

Comment: The joys of reinventing the wheel.